# Bootstrap - I want to change my Home Page Banner randonly - output images have to be responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
var image = new Array();
image[0]="images/Arcade.jpg";
image[1]="images/Arcade2.jpg";
```

Having trouble making the code for the images to out put as responsive images. Using Boostrap and jQuery. I can make it show two images at random but they are not responsive.

(this code below in the body)

```
var num = Math.round((image.length-1)*Math.random());
document.write("<img src='" + image[num] + "' />");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "img-responsive" class:

```
var num = Math.round((image.length-1)*Math.random());
document.write("<img  class="img-responsive" src='" + image[num] + "' />");
```